# Entity Framework - Find complete foreign key information

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Showing by a simple example tables

```
Table: Customer
--------------
Id: int
Name: varchar
Order_Id: int (Foreign Key => Order.Id)

Table: Order
------------
Id: int
Number: varchar
```

Now, I have the below code to get the navigation properties and works perfectly fine.

```
public static string[] GetForeignKeyNames(this DbContext context, Type entityType)
{
    var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

    // Get the mapping between CLR types and metadata OSpace
    var objectItemCollection = ((ObjectItemCollection)metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace));

    // Get metadata for given CLR type
    var entityMetadata = metadata
            .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
            .Single(e => objectItemCollection.GetClrType(e) == entityType);

    return entityMetadata.NavigationProperties.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
}
```

Above, when called for entityType = typeof(Customer), returns "Order"

However, now for the above navigation property in the function, i want to know what is the column name in Customer that is the foreign key with Order table. i.e, I want information like

```
NavigationTable: Order
NavigationColumn: Id
SourceTable: Customer
SourceColumn: Order_Id
```

How can I get the above column information from the navigation properties? Or do I need to have a different approach?

Thanks